# Get all occurances of matches pattern perl

Tags: regex, perl

if we are in the following case:

```
 my $str = <<EO_STR;
   Name=Value1 Adress=Value4
   Name=Value2 Adress=Value5
   Name=Value3 Adress=Value6
EO_STR
```

I have a table `"T1"` in the database with columns: `("Name", "Address")` and I want to put on the column `"Name"` values `"value1,Value2,Value3"` and on the column `"Adress"` values `"Value4,Value5,Value6"`
in this case we have :

```
my @matches = $str =~ /Name=(.*?)\nAdress=(.*?)\n/g;
```

how can we use `$1` and `$2` with `@matches` in order to get separately all occurence of Name and Adresse in order to insert them on the Table `T1`?

Comment: Your pattern does not match anything. There's a typo in there (_Adress_ vs _Adresse_), and the quantifier is wrong. Please post your **real code**.

Comment: thank you, I corrected I forgot Address with "E" in the code because I was in French version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All captures of all matches are returned, so you'd have to group them up.

```
use List::Util 1.29 qw( pairs );

for ( pairs( $str =~ /Name=(.*) Address=(.*)/g ) ) {
   my @matches = @$_;
    ...
}
```

That said, it's far more common to grab the matches iteratively.

```
while ($str =~ /Name=(.*) Address=(.*)/g) {
   my @matches = ( $1, $2 );
   ...
}
```

Comment: thank you very much @ikegami, it answers correctly to my need

Answer (score 3):

Regex is not always the right tool for the job. Your data looks a lot like it's just key/value pairs. Use [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) to break it up. No need for a pattern match here.

Your code and data doesn't match, so I've gone with what the code said.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = <<EO_STR;
   Name=Value1
   Adress=Value4
   Name=Value2
   Adress=Value5
   Name=Value3
   Adress=Value6
EO_STR

my $fields;
foreach my $pair (split /\n/, $str) {
    my ($key, $value) = split /=/, $pair;
    $key =~ s/^\s+//;
    push @{ $fields->{$key} }, $value;
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $fields;
```

The code will create this data structure:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Name' => [
                      'Value1',
                      'Value2',
                      'Value3'
                    ],
          'Adress' => [
                        'Value4',
                        'Value5',
                        'Value6'
                      ]
        };
```

You can now access these two array references and use them to insert data into your table.

Comment: Nitpick: *"No need for a pattern match here."* but `split` uses one 

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, but I want the solution to be in regex, 
because the example that I posted normally is not the one in reality just to have an idea on how to do this with the regex, on the other hand in the reality I do not have key = value, I have a text paragraph on which j apply my regex and I can extract values ​​$ 1, $ 2... and this text is repetitive on other paragraph it means I can apply the same regex for the other paragraph and it pulls me the same info ,on the other hand I do not know how to apply the regex to send me $ 1, $ 2... of all occurrence s in a boocle

Comment: @Red_Developper so in short, you've wasted my time but not asking your real question. Please don't do that. It discourages people from helping you and others, and it wastes everyone's time.

Answer (score 2):

I have done the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use v5.28;
my $str = <<EO_STR;
    Name=Value1 Adress=Value4
    Name=Value2 Adress=Value5
    Name=Value3 Adress=Value6
EO_STR
my @array;
for my $a (split(/\n/, $str)) {
    my %res = $a =~ m/(\w+)=(\w+)/g;
    push @array, \%res;
}
for my $a (@array) {
    for my $b (sort keys %{$a}) {
      "\n", <INPUT_FILE> );   say $b.'->'.$a->{$b};
    }
}
```

It creates this structure:

```
@array = [
    {
        Name->Value1,
        Adress->Value4
    },
    ...
];
```